# Custom Sorting Algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Hey guys so I want to write a small Java Program that helps me sort a list. Imagine the list looks like this:
**Apples, Grapefruit, Bananas, Pineapples, Coconuts**

Now I don't want to sort alphabetically or anything like that but for example by what fruit I like the most, so the sorted list could look like this: **Coconuts, Bananas, Apples, Pineapples, Grapefruit**

My idea so far was that it could kinda go like that: Apples is written into the list. Then Grapefruit and apple is compared and the user says what he likes more (here Apples) so Grapefruits move under Apples. Then it compares Bananas with eg Apples and the user tells the program he likes Bananas more so it goes above Apples and doesnt have to compare with Grapefruit anymore which saves a lot of time. The Program should handle a few hundred entries and comparisions in the end so saving time by asking fewer questions will save a lot of time. Am I on the right track? Also what would be the best way to input the list, an array, an arraylist, or...?

How should this be implemented? Is there a fitting sorting Algorithm? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Needs code, what have you attempted?  2.  Look at providing your own custom Comparator: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)

Comment: I @valoon welcome to stackoverflow community! You are almost on the track but, the algorithm are nothing but a contructed flow (Sequence of statements executed in a flow based on some conditions). In your case to sort the elements (Fruits) based on likeliness, you will have to associate a parity value (likeliness) with each element in list and then you can apply a normal sorting (a > b) to sort items! in short, assigning each element likliness and then sorting will become your custom algorithm. 
Hope that helps!

Comment: It is called **insertion sort**.

Comment: Like markspace stated take a look at 'Comparator'.
A core part is implementing any two items. By having that there is some meta algorithms to handle sorting a whole collection. But you can skip that detail since java does offer you a default way of sorting. Default in terms of that it is stated in the documentation - it could be insertion sort, but I do not know. So probably it is not the fastest way; but efficiency depends on various different factors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build a Binary Search Tree.

As you're inserting new fruits, you ask the user which they like best, to find where to insert the new fruit node. To keep the number of questions down, keep the tree Balanced.

Once the "preference tree" has been built, you can iterate the tree depth-first, assigning incremental "preference values" to each fruit, and build a `Map<String, Integer>`, so you can quickly lookup any fruits preference values, aka sort sequence number.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `Collections.sort` with a custom comparator that asks for user input.

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
Collections.sort(fruits, (a, b) -> {
    System.out.println("Do you prefer " + a + " or " + b + "?");
    String preference = sc.next();
    return preference.equals(a) ? -1 : preference.equals(b) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Comment: Good idea, but dangerous. Humans are fickle, and may not answer consistently, violating the requirements of `Comparator`, potentially causing the sort algorithm to throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you, this looks quite good so far! However when first b is chosen and then a, the third question is the same as the second, or also when chosen like a b a then the fourth is the same as the third, any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Yes, it seems the sorting algorithm used by `Collections.sort` does some redundant comparisons. You can use the same comparator in another sorting algorithm, of course; so long as the algorithm you choose never does any redundant comparisons then both issues are addressed.

Comment: Or your comparator could remember answers and repeat them without asking the user again. Still won't solve the "rock paper scissors" issue, though (which @Andreas might've meant) . If the algorithm asks me all three pairs, I'll always say I prefer the winning object of each pair, which the algorithm might not like.

Comment: If you're caching comparison results, then you can do a DFS or BFS in the cache to solve the rock-paper-scissors problem.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is fine, but consider also this alternative:

You could store the fruits in a max-heap, which can be done with an ArrayList (when you don't know the number of fruits beforehand) or a plain array.

When you insert a new fruit, it is appended at the end of the array, and as you let it sift up (according to the heap algorithm), you ask the user for the result of the comparison(s), until the fruit is considered less liked than the one compared with (or it becomes the root -- at index 0).

As post processing, you need to pull out all elements from the top of the heap, again using the appropriate heap algorithm. They will come out in sorted order.